# shiny cannot save upload file in local disk

Tags: r, shiny

I want shiny to upload and save data in the local disk, everything works fine except the saving part, below is the code, any help?
PS: There is no error message.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
responsesDir <- file.path("c:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/11") #save at this dir
ui = fluidPage(
  fileInput("FileInput", "File select"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$FileInput, {
    infile <- input$FileInput
    read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE)
  })

  data_save <- eventReactive(
    input$FileInput,
    {write.csv(datasetInput(), file = paste0(responsesDir, '/iris_set.csv'),
               row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)}) #name iris_set.csv for example

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable(datasetInput())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you get any error message? Please [edit] your question to include that.

Comment: There is no error message.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after googling for couple of hours, I figured out by myself. Replacing the `eventReactive` from data_save line to `observeEvent` it worked.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
responsesDir <- file.path("c:/Users/Vincent/Desktop/ls") #save at this dir
ui = fluidPage(
  fileInput("FileInput", "File select"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$FileInput, {
    infile <- input$FileInput
    read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE)
  })

  data_save <- observeEvent(
    input$FileInput,
    {write.csv(datasetInput(), file = paste0(responsesDir, '/fuck_you.csv'),
               row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)}) #name iris_set.csv for example

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable(datasetInput())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```